# Confusion about dimensions on optical absorption near the bandgap formula for direct band gap semiconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics, dimensional-analysis, optical-materials

I'm trying to replicate some results from this paper (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/44924/) on the changes in refractive index due to the band filling effect, however I'm stuck at some dimensionalities I don't unuderstand. The formula for the optical absorption near the bandgap in a direct-gap semidconductor with parabolic bands is given by:

$$\alpha(E)=\frac{C}{E}\sqrt{E-E_g}$$

for $E>E_g$. From above, $C$ should have dimensions of $[Energy]^{-1/2}[Length]^{-1}$. Yet, in the paper, they present it as $[cm]^{-1}[s]^{-1/2}$. Is there some sort of convention I'm not aware of?

I'm able to replicate the curves profile by inserting the given $C$ in the given dimensions and energy in eV, but I'm about 7 orders of magnitude off.